# How do I drop a beacon?

Tags: warzone-2100

While playing a game of 4v4 with a mix of humans and bots, I was under heavy attack when my bot allies said "Drop a beacon, John" (Or similar, I forget their exact words).

What on earth does that mean?  How do I drop a beacon?  What will that do?

Answer (score 2):

In [this](http://guide.wz2100.net/minimap) article under *Beacon* section you will see that you can drop beacon on minimap (*Alt + H* by default). You may need to send some message like "Go" or similar to make AI send army there.